# Armazenar perguntas de um quiz em java

Tags: java

Tenho um jogo em quiz feito em java e gostaria da adicionar numa classe as perguntas que apareceriam na tela para o usuário, pensei em usar ArryList, porém não está dando certo. 
Eu tentei isso:

```
    package model;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author Aluno
 */
public class Perguntas {
   public static ArrayList<String> preciclagem = new ArrayList<String>();
   public static ArrayList<String> psus = new ArrayList<String>();
   public static ArrayList<String> precursos = new ArrayList<String>();


   public static void Preciclagem(){

       preciclagem.add("1°) Reciclar é uma forma de reduzir o lixo depositado no ambiente\n" +
"e todos podemos colaborar para a conscientização da sociedade sobre\n" +
"os benefícios dessa atividade.");

       preciclagem.add("2°) Muitas pessoas utilizam essa forma de vida como fonte de renda, \n" +
"e ainda ajudam o meio ambiente. O profissional que destina o tempo \n" +
"para reciclagem é totalmente importante para o ciclo e redução da \n" +
"produção de lixos.");

       preciclagem.add("3°) São muitos os materiais que são recicláveis e podemos fazer a \n" +
"separação na nossa casa e no local de trabalho. Os materiais que\n" +
"são recicláveis são: pilhas, acrílico, espuma, plástico, tecido e componentes\n" +
"eletrônicos.");

       preciclagem.add("4°) Os materiais que serão reciclados são transportados para uma \n" +
"cooperativa ou são recolhidos em locais estratégicos, esses materiais \n" +
"são limpos e reprocessados em novos materiais para a produção industrial.");

        preciclagem.add("5°) Mesmo com o avanço da tecnológia, é impossivel fazer com que os itens \n" +
"não reciclaveis se tornem futuramente reciclaveis.");

   }
```

Quando tento chamar a primeira pergunta da esse erro:

```
public class Principal {
    public static void main(String args[]){
       System.out.println(preciclagem.get(0));

    }

}
```

Erro que não tem nada armazenado:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at controller.Principal.main(Principal.java:21)
C:\Users\enzo\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 0 segundos)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não inicializou as perguntas/objetos através do método Preciclagem da classe Perguntas, tente isso.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Perguntas.Preciclagem();
    System.out.println(Perguntas.preciclagem.get(0);
}
```

Comment: por isso eu recomendo você usar o método construtor para inicializar essas perguntas (caso não saiba o que é o método construtor recomendo pesquisar) [links]( https://www.devmedia.com.br/construtores-em-java/28618 , https://www.guj.com.br/t/o-que-e-construtor/70766 , https://www.guj.com.br/t/qual-a-sintaxe-para-criar-um-metodo-construtor/66748 , http://www.mballem.com/post/declaracao-de-construtores-em-java/)

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi o método construtor serve para adicionar as informações as variáveis, mas no meu caso eu não quero adicionar mais perguntas nessa classe, como o método construtor seria útil?

Comment: Seria pois ele só é chamado ao criar o objeto, no seu código você pode chamar quantas vezes quiser o método Preciclagem().